# How to install WinPCAP from within my MSI installer?

Tags: windows-installer, pcap

I am developing a product that will use WinPCAP for ethernet packet capturing. 
Is it possible to install WinPCAP from my own MSI or it must be installed seperately ?

If it is possible to install it from my own MSI, can someone let me know how ? I also have to support silent installation.

Answer (score 0):

If you want silent install you have to pay for the professional edition.

I don't use MSI, but there must be a way for an MSI installer to run an external executable as part of the installation process. And that external executable can be the WinPcap installer.